# Why won't this do-while loop break out once the condition is not met?

Tags: c++, do-while

what's up, I've got another issue with this huge project I'm working on.

The project is for school, but this isn't the entire piece. For more information on the project you can look [here](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/11/projects/comp11f11p1.pdf).

So I have to take input from the user in the following format:

`p 11:45 12:15`

It will always start with either a `p` or an `s` and will have two times during which there is a call on a phone. The big idea is to compare cell phone plans taking into account daytime minutes, night minutes, etc.

Right now I'm having trouble taking the input. Every time I run the program, it doesn't care if I start the input with an `s` and just keeps waiting for more data. Frustrating part is that it was working not too long ago.

Here's my code:

```
string c;
string end = "s";
string start = "p";
int temp_start_hour;
int temp_start_min;
int temp_end_hour;
int temp_end_min;
char colon;

do {
    cin >> c;
    cout << c << endl;
    if (c != start && c != end)
    {
        cout << "ERROR IN INPUT" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (c != end)
    {
        cin >> temp_start_hour >> colon >> temp_start_min;
        cin >> temp_end_hour >> colon >> temp_end_min;

        begin_hours[i] = temp_start_hour;
        begin_min[i] = temp_start_min;
        end_hours[i] = temp_end_hour;
        end_min[i] = temp_end_min;
    }
    i++;
} while (c != end);
```

Comment: It's official, this code on its own works fine but won't work with the rest of my program... Anybody want to take a look at the source? It can be found http://pastebin.com/VUaBDbVM, it's about 220 lines and something's messing this bit of the code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (with a couple tweaks to make it compile) is working fine for me. Could you post the input you are sending to it that causes the program to fail?

Comment: This is part of a 220 line full code, do you think it could be something in the other parts? Should I post the full code?
The input, by the way was:
`p 11:45 12:15`
`s`

Comment: The input "p 11:45 12:15 s" works fine for me, too. It's conceivable that other code in the file is causing a problem. Do you know which line it is stuck waiting for input on? You could break up your cin statements into one line for each input and mix some couts in between to track where you are in the program.

Comment: It only takes input once though, that's what's making me so confused. This is the only point in the function where it takes input, the rest is all manipulating the data. This is the first part of my program. http://pastebin.com/VUaBDbVM You can see the rest there if you'd like.

Comment: Your while loop near the bottom of your program (in total function) has an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm so stupid! I never did i++ for the iterator... wow...
Thank you Kurt for the help! Thank you to everyone for the time and energy!

Answer (score 0):

If your input stream gets into an error state your loop will never end. That's because if its in an error state, nothing will get written into any variable used in `cin >> c` and `c` will keep its last value forever.

To fix this you should really use a `while(cin)` loop instead of a do-while loop, or check `if( cin.fail() )` after `cin >> c`.

Or you could call `cin.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit )` before starting the loop. That would enable a C++ exception thrown from the stream input function if anything goes wrong.

Comment: I'm still confused by this, though. Don't I want a do-while loop because I want it to run the first time no matter what? I still don't fully understand how it will keep the value for c, shouldn't it hit the `while (c != end);` and, if it is the end, break out?

Comment: @JamesRoseman: If `cin` is not working then it cannot read data into c. That's why the value does not change.

Comment: All you have to do to accomplish that is set the value to a passing condition before the loop starts

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VUaBDbVM It may be because of something somewhere else in the code? I can't figure out why. I tested the bit in the question on its own and it works fine, so it must be, but this is the only part of the program that takes input...